# Mongoose efficient finding and populating

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to find and populate documents some of which have references to another collection and some don't.

Example:

```
var collectionA={
                 {
                 "topic":"TopicA",
                 "text";"TextA")
                 },
                 {
                  "topic":"Topic1",
                  "text":"Text1"}
                 }
                }

var collectionB={
                 {
                 "topic":"TopicB",
                 "text":"TextB"
                 "reference":["id","id"]
                 },
                 {
                 "topic":"Topic2",
                 "text":"Text2"
                 "reference":[]
                 }
                }
```

and I have a request as follows which allows me to identify the documents I want:

```
   req.body={"topic":["TopicA","TopicB"]}
```

What is the most efficient way to find the relevant documents and populate them to provide a fully populated result, in the fewest number of database calls as possible:

```
{"topic":"TopicA","text":"TextA"},
{"topic":"TopicB","text":"TextB","reference":[{populated document}
{populated document}]},
```

I am trying to use something like:

```
collections.find({"topic": $in req.body.top}, function(err,result){
    collections.populate(result,{path:'references'}, function (err,result){
//do something
    });
})
```

Is this on the right track?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference other documents in mongoose you need to use [Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

If you want to reference a topic by id you would need to have something like the following in your schema: `{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'collectionA' }`